# What kind of error model would be suitable for this error plot?

Tags: data-visualization, residuals, scatterplot

I have done a regression analysis and have plotted the residuals vs. the predicted values. I would like to know what kind of error model would be suitable for the picture I add. I am a novice in the field and therefore I would love suggestions, references, etc.

I am modelling weight of people using a linear function of height, times a continuous function of their income. I am estimating this continuous function non-parametrically using smoothing. After I get estimate for this continuous function, I am getting estimate for the regression coefficients for the linear part. I have plotted the logarithm of the residuals against the predicted values from this model.

So the model is

$$Weight = (a+b\times Height)\times f(Income)\times\epsilon$$

For the time being I am concerned about modelling $\log(\epsilon)$. The plot you see is that of $\log(\epsilon)$ vs. predicted values of weight. However, if someone can hint if it is possible to model the errors for the linear regression and smoothing separately also, I would be grateful. Although I don't think that is necessary; my $\epsilon$ takes care of this.

What I think can be concluded is that the error variances are non-constant but the errors are uncorrelated. What do you feel? Can you please suggest some distributional properties of errors? The errors can be assumed to have zero mean. How do I model their variances? Is normality a good assumption?

[image]

Comment: What are we looking at? What is the model? What are the variables? Where did the data come from? Etc. This is unanswerable at present.

Comment: Kindly see the edited question.

Comment: I am talking of $\log(\epsilon)$. The $\epsilon$ as mentioned are positive.

Comment: Kindly see the edited plot. Earlier I plotted log of errors vs predicted values. Now I have plotted log of errors vs. log of predicted values. Still uncorrelated